# Reading values from JSON without decimal points as float or double

Tags: java, json, parsing, integer, double

There is a `JSON` array with hundreds of values. I want to parse an `array` which also got `values` with and without decimal points. As soon there's an value without a decimal point i get an error message.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double

For example i am reading the following values:

```
99.06   //ok
4038.6  //ok
9448.8  //ok
3810    //error, since this will be interpreted as integer
```

This is the code i am working with currently:

```
double x = (double) jsonArray.get(7);
```

The `JSON` got the following structure:

`"array:"[[6 values here, 7th value is supposed to be a double value, x values here], [ same ], [ ... ], ...]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't type cast the variable if you are not sure that its an Integer or Double. Always use Wrapper class. Try the following

```
 Double.parseDouble(a.get(7).toString());
```